# 9.223372 Ether Limit?

Tags: parity

This is a weird question but it's hard to search for because I get mathematical uses of the term "limit" and and other uses of 9.2, etc.  So.

Question: is 9.223372 ETH a significant number?  Because no matter how many ETH I send (on mainnet) the limit seems to be 9.223372.

The account has MUCH more than 9.23ETH.  Also, it sends the 9.223372 each time.  So I can make multiple transactions but each one sends only 9.223372ETH.

I am using Parity latest and the blockchain is fully synced.  I am on mainnet.

Please do not overthink.  Either this number is going to be obvious, or the idea of a limit is going to be obvious.

If I don't get an obvious answer, then I need to start looking at logs.  And then I will come back with a specific question.  But I thought maybe "everyone knows" that 9.22 is a magic number so I wanted to ask first.

Comment: That magic number is probably your available account balance?

Comment: @5chdn Good thinking but no.  I edited the question to reflect that I have much more than this amount in the wallet.  And I have made multiple transactions.  The problem is that they each are for this 9.223372 limit.  Does parity have a way of throttling the amount of ETH/transaction?

Comment: It was reported previously but I cannot find the question. The problem is javascript numbers do not have enough precision. You have to encode amounts as bigNumber. For example `web3.toWei(100, "ether")`.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  If you add this as an answer I will mark it correct.

Comment: Code snippet of sending code would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was reported previously but I cannot find the question, will update later when I find it.

The problem is javascript numbers do not have enough precision. You have to encode amounts as a bigNumber. For example you have to use `web3.toWei(100, "ether");`.